# passing data between threads and notify reciever thread

Tags: multithreading, architecture, chat, messaging

i am writing a chat application by C# (this is obvious from my last question). i want to have multiple threads. in client side application one thread for receiving and another for other works. in server side there would be more threads. for instance for every user there will be three threads.
my first question is that how can i pass data between threads and notify the receiver thread?
second question is which architecture you suggest for this application? i have about two months time for complete this application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have to show us some sort of effort in solving the problem. StackOverflow isn't a 'code-order' website. What have you tried? What possible solutions do you think there are? Have you tried looking around for this answer anywhere else?

Comment: this is another question about multithreading and differs from previous.